# Custom controller dies when launched in global launch file

Tags: controller, config, ros

I have a custom robot consisting of different nodelets and controllers which are organized in sub-packages:

```
.
├── project
│   ├── launch
├── project_description
│   └── urdf
├── project_hardware
│   ├── config
│   ├── launch
├── project_logic
│   ├── launch
├── project_networking
└── project_vision
```

I implemented a custom `LedController` to control some Leds on my hardware following the usual ROS approach (i.e. custom interface, handle, controller, message).

The controller works fine (i.e. setting the Leds to given values via the corresponding topic), when I am launching my `hardware.launch` which is located in `project_hardware`.

However, the `LedController` dies (and also kills the `controller_manager` which in turn kills all my other controllers), when I am launching everything with my global launch file `robot.launch` which is located in a different sub-package called `project` only.

When I move the Led part from the `hardware.xml` to a separate file (`led.launch`) and launch `robot.launch` first and then `led.launch` everything works. When I am including `led.launch` in `robot.launch` (see below), it does not work.

Since the difference between working and not working is only a matter of including `led.launch` or starting it by hand via `roslaunch`, I am out of debugging ideas. I appreciate any little hint pointing me to further debugging steps and eventually to the solution of my problem. Please let me know, if you need any further information.

My `hardware.launch`:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="nodelet_manager" default="nodelet_manager" />
  <node name="$(arg nodelet_manager)" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" args="manager" />

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find project_description)/urdf/ccs_robot.xacro'" />

  <include file="$(find project_hardware)/launch/hardware.xml">
    <arg name="nodelet_manager" value="$(arg nodelet_manager)" />
  </include>
</launch>
```

My `hardware.xml` with the `LedController`:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="nodelet_manager" />
  <rosparam file="$(find project_hardware)/config/drive_controller.yaml" />
  <node name="drive_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="drive_controller --shutdown-timeout 2" />
  <node name="driver" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" args="load project/RobotNodelet $(arg nodelet_manager)" >
    <param name="rate" value="100" />
    <param name="ros_hw_velocity_conversion_factor" value="5.615" />
    <param name="ros_hw_led_max_value" value="64" />
  </node>

  <rosparam file="$(find project_hardware)/config/distance_sensor_controller.yaml" />
  <node name="distance_sensor_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="distance_sensor_controller --shutdown-timeout 2" />
  <rosparam file="$(find project_hardware)/config/led_controller.yaml" />
  <node name="led_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="led_controller --shutdown-timeout 2" />
</launch>
```

My `robot.launch`:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="nodelet_manager" default="nodelet_manager" />
  <node name="$(arg nodelet_manager)" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" args="manager" />

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find project_description)/urdf/ccs_robot.xacro'" />
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"/>

  <include file="$(find project_vision)/launch/feature_extraction.xml">
    <arg name="nodelet_manager" value="$(arg nodelet_manager)" />
  </include>
  <include file="$(find project_logic)/launch/demo_app.xml" />
  <include file="$(find project_logic)/launch/logic.xml">
    <arg name="nodelet_manager" value="$(arg nodelet_manager)" />
  </include>
  <include file="$(find project_hardware)/launch/hardware.xml">
    <arg name="nodelet_manager" value="$(arg nodelet_manager)" />
  </include>
  <!--<include file="$(find project_hardware)/launch/led.launch" />-->
  <include file="$(find project_networking)/launch/monitoring.launch" />
</launch>
```

My `hardware.xml` without the `LedController`:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="nodelet_manager" />
  <rosparam file="$(find project_hardware)/config/drive_controller.yaml" />
  <node name="drive_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="drive_controller --shutdown-timeout 2" />
  <node name="driver" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" args="load project/RobotNodelet $(arg nodelet_manager)" >
    <param name="rate" value="100" />
    <param name="ros_hw_led_max_value" value="64" />
  </node>

  <rosparam file="$(find project_hardware)/config/distance_sensor_controller.yaml" />
  <node name="distance_sensor_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="distance_sensor_controller --shutdown-timeout 2" />
</launch>
```

My `led.launch` containing the Led part moved from the `hardware.xml`:

```
<launch>
  <rosparam file="$(find project_hardware)/config/led_controller.yaml" />
  <node name="led_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" args="led_controller --shutdown-timeout 2" />
</launch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on launch files everything seems fine but what I think your mistake was when writing the nodes is that you initialized the node of 2 different code with same values that when 1 launches, stops the other one and so all will break (but not sure without seeing the errors).

You can try adding `ros::init_options::AnonymousName` to your node.init and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try that.